# Pattern matching of mutable values using F#

Tags: f#, pattern-matching, mutable

I would like to point out a 'risky' part in F#. Consider the following code

```
let mutable a, b as ab = 0, 0
a <- 4
a
ab
```

You will get `a = 4` and `ab = 0, 0`. It is probably a correct behaviour, I just wanted to point it out and know your opinion. Do you find this behaviour logical or not, and why? I have some problems to accept it, because I have always assumed that (a, b) and ab should be identical.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you run `let mutable a, b as ab = 0, 0` in F# interactive you will get :

```
val mutable ab : int * int = (0, 0)
val mutable b : int = 0
val mutable a : int = 0
```

Which mean the expression has created 3 different and separate values. Modifying one value wont effect other values

Answer (score 3):

It is true that this may be confusing at first, but once you understand how F# treates the declaration (as explained by Ankur), it should make good sense.

You can get the other behavior (where modifying one value also modifies a tuple) if you use reference cells instead of `mutable` variables:

```
let a, b as ab = ref 0, ref 0
a := 4
!(fst ab) // returns 4
```